# SQL Table Design Modification based on data roles or implementation convenience?

Tags: sql, database-design

I've got an existing SQL table structure that looks like this:

```
Orders
- order_id
- organisation_id
- [all the rest of the order data]

Organisations
- organisation_id
- [all the rest of the organisation data]

Users
- user ID
- [all the rest of the user data]
```

I'm trying to change the `Orders` table so that an Order can be linked to either an `Organisation` or a `User`. I've got two ideas:

#### Option A

- Add field `orders.user_id`, and then set either `user_id` or `organisation_id` to null for each order, indicating whether the order was placed by a user or organisation.

#### Option B

- Add a table `orderers` (or similar) and then add fields `organisations.orderer_id` and `users.orderer_id`. Then, users and organisations are both orderers, and orderers place orders.

#### Evaluation

Option B's role-based approach seems to make good sense and seems to be more extensible, but I just can't help but think about the hassle the extra `JOIN`s are going to cause, in terms of performance and SQL complexity.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Related: [How do we implement an IS-A relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361381/how-do-we-implement-an-is-a-relationship), and [How do I map an IS-A relationship into a database?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5501/how-do-i-map-an-is-a-relationship-into-a-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option B will actually cause you extra work on building the joins, but not necessarily worst performance, depending on your situation.
Consider this scenario:
- 1k organisations
- 20k users
- 1M orders
With scenario A you will have to take into consideration:
- you will have one more column on a 1M rows table
- you will probably want one index for user_id and one for organisation_id so if you want to find all the orders belonging to each you can find them faster.
This means your inserts/deletes would be slower than on scenario B which needs only, in reference to your largest table:
- only one index on orderer_id.
I think best choice will end up depending on your specific situation, but take this into consideration.

Comment: That's a great thought - I hadn't considered the volume of records in each table.